# Superscript text in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, format, ssrs-2008-r2, superscript

How can I superscript in SSRS. We are building an invoice and the users want the report to read

**'business [1][1]'** where the [1][1] are superscripted in the text.  We've searched high and low and couldn't find the formatting, or paragraph settings to make the text superscript.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried making the text HTML  markup type and wrap the text with <sup> your field </sup> ?

Comment: @Harry we did, it didn't work - I will try again but we had no success with it. it just appeared as business[1][1] like regular text